# Activity not launching correctly although described in Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.StyledCustom" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.StyledCustom" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm including the SplashActivity.java (I am using ActionBarSherlock):

```
package com.app.android;

import com.app.android.R;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;

public class SplashActivity extends SherlockActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        Thread timerSplash = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    int i = 0;
                    while(i < 1000){
                        i+=100;
                        sleep(100);
                    }
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.app.android.MainActivity"));
                }catch(Exception ex){
                }finally{
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        timerSplash.start();
    }
}
```

What I am facing is that my MainActivity is getting Launched before SplashActivity.
Also a warning is generated at MainActivity activity node in AndroidManifest.xml : **"Exported activity does not require permission"**

Can any one say what is happening?

Comment: also while running the following message is generated at the console.

ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.app.android/.MainActivity } from null (pid=21876, uid=2000) requires null

Comment: i think if you remove `<intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>` intent filter from `MainActivity` then your code working perfectlly

Comment: It doesn't work @imrankhan. Same problem.

Comment: Please PLEASE for the love of sanity do not make your users wait like this for absolutely no reason. If you have some work that needs to be done before your app can be loaded then do that work in the background while showing a splash screen. But as it is now you are simply wasting their time by forcing them to wait for no reason each and every time they want to use your application. If you are dead set on wasting your users time like this, please see: [Android Splash Screens Done Right](http://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/01/01/android-splash-screens-done-right/) for good info on how to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Manifast.xml:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.StyledCustom" >
        </activity>
```

And Class as Below

```
public class SplashActivity extends SherlockActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        Thread timerSplash = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    int i = 0;
                    while(i < 1000){
                        i+=100;
                        sleep(100);
                    }
                   Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                }catch(Exception ex){
                }finally{
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        timerSplash.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just after DDMS pre int the following is generated in the eclipse console.

also while running the following message is generated at the console. ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.app.android/.MainActivity } from null (pid=21876, uid=2000) requires null

Comment: Well the problem is what you might find little bit weird is that I updated the Eclipse as well as SDK. And now the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

define Activity as in Manifast.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.StyledCustom" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and start as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.app.android", "com.app.android.MainActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```